# Sending / Receiving / Configuring TCP/IP Protocol Suite Request / Response Packets in CANalyzer using CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe, automotive

We have requirement to test TCP/IP Protocol Suite ( TCP/UDP/IP/ARP/ICMP/Ethernet) using CANAalyzer / CANoe with CAPL  and have below queries :-

1. Are there any API provided  to send / receive  /
   configure different protocols packets within TCP/IP Protocol Suite like ARP 
   / ICMP / TCP / UDP / IP 
   ?
2. If no separate API available , how  can we send / receive / configure the protocol packets ?  Do we need to set / get raw packet and create / decode using CAPL scripts ?

Comment: This answer is best if comes from Vector Support, which they will gladly share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In help sections there are functions for UDP and TCP communication. Some of which are TcpOpen,  OnTcpReceive,  kindly check.